# PHP comet usleep blocking apache mpm?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, comet

I've a comet there I run an while loop in this way

```
$items = $statement->fetchAll();//statement is a PDO Statement
$iteration = 0;
while(count($items) == 0 && $iteration < 100){
    $items = $statement->fetchAll();
    usleep(10000);
    ++$iteration;
}
```

When the comet runs I can see all other HTTP requests are pending. even non-database requests are pending. Why ?

Comment: I donno may be. postgresql serializes all parallal quries if they are invoked through one same connection.and you are using persistent connection. so the same connection is being reused for all queries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually commit using `PDO::commit` as the request are being hold in a transaction.

Please see the docs about this behavior:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.commit.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Comment: Do I need to commit in the `comet` code where `select` operation is being done ?

Comment: The comet is doing select query doing a commit there  reports there is no active transaction