# switching apache mpm on gentoo

Tags: php, apache, concurrency, apache2

I've a gentoo box where I've done ite default gentoo installation. now I want to change its mpm as my [comet is blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126465/php-comet-usleep-blocking-apache-mpm)  all other requests. Should `worker` mpm resolve this concurrency issue ? and how can I change the mpm on gentoo ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the APACHE2_MPMS to the desired MPM(s):

```
# echo 'APACHE2_MPMS="worker"' >> /etc/portage/make.conf
```

I don't know if it'll fix your concurrency issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `APACHE2_MPMS="prefork"`  in `/etc/portage/make.conf` as this is the only module where you can be sure that there will be no concurrency issues. The reason for that is, that this module uses a single thread for every request.